# how to remove mongodb terminal error msg?

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

Getting this in every terminal window that I open on my Mac. Wondering how can I get rid of it... I did brew uninstall --force mongodb, deleted 3 folders that contained word "mongodb" in them

```
-bash: mongodb-install-directory: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a line that I had to delete from `.bash_profile`!

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- Look for mongodb entries in your ~/.bashrc file.
- Look at the folder ~/Library/LaunchAgents and find suspicious entries.

Comment: bashrc just has sdkman

and launchagent contains only those things:
com.google.keystone.agent.plist com.spotify.webhelper.plist org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist